# SCOM - report on failed logons on workstations

Tags: active-directory, system-center, reporting, scom

I have been asked to create a report that gives us the following data in a SCOM report and export to .csv:

- Timestamp
- Workstation
- Account Name
- Status and Sub Status Codes

I know I'll have to work with Security Log Event ID 4625. We have multiple DC's.
The main issue is I have no idea where to get the Workstation from...

Anyone have a idea?

Comment: do you have error code looks like 0x0000..... somthing like that?

Comment: The error code doesn't really matter here. it's just getting the workstation from which authentication is attempted that I have to figure out :)

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/antoni/2018/02/03/operations-manager-101-create-an-event-collection-rule-for-monitoring-server-restarts-2/